# Create a program in Python that works with mathematical operations

Tags: data-structures, operating-systems

Write a program that takes N numbers as input and prints all 3^(N-1) equations that can be formed by inserting the operators +, -, or * between these numbers (keeping them in the initial order). Also count how many unique answers there are and print that as well.

So far, I have this code

```
import math


def expressions():

userinput= input("enter some numbers:")

operations= ['+',' -',' *')

thelist=[1::]

head= L[0]

if len(expression)==0 :
    return[]
    else:
```

What I'm having trouble with understanding, is do I iterate over the operations so they alternate with the input that are numbers?

Comment: Coding questions and questions about writing code (e.g., how to write Python code) are off-topic here.  The algorithmic aspects are relevant, but you'd need to remove the code and focus on the algorithm.  Also, I can't tell what your question is.  Have you tried working through some small examples by hand?  If you'd like to ask this question here, please edit it (see the 'edit' link under the question) to remove the code, re-focus on algorithms, and elaborate in greater detail on what your question is and what your thoughts are and what approaches you've considered.